# How to I write a join to constrain on an attribute of the target of a belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The model Reading.rb includes `belongs_to :reader`

I'm trying to implement a filter on 'index' of the readings by joining through the association:

```
readings = Reading.all.order(:date)
if params[:reader_name]
    readings = readings.join(:reader).where('reader.name like ?', params[:reader_name])
end
```

I get:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into String
```

Comment: 'join' has to be 'joins'

Answer (score 0):

```
readings.joins(:reader).where('readers.name like ?', params[:reader_name])
```

As pointed out by bmargulies `joins` has a plural S at the end, and the table name is also plural.